# Голый репозиторий, как работает git init --bare

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Если набрать git init, то в папку добавится .git и у репозитория будет рабочая директория, а если git init --bare тоже самое, но содержимое не в папке.git,а в той которой выполнили и у этого репозитория нет рабочей директории и в этот репозиторий можно выполнять команды push,pull. Вопрос, у git есть переменная в которой указана рабочая директория? И если есть, тогда можно переопрелелить и он будет следить за другой директорией? И еще вопрос, если на удаленный репозиторий bare кидаются файлы гита (blob, tree) и там нет рабочей директории с файлами, то при клонировании файлы создаются из объектов гита?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это работает немного не так. git репозиторий первичен, а рабочая копия вторична, поэтому связь идет в другую сторону, от рабочей копии к репозиторию.

Он может существовать и без рабочей копии (можно создать `git init --bare` или сделать clone). К одному репозиторию можно подключить одну или несколько рабочих копий. В качестве рабочей копии можно использовать вообще любую директорию.

При выполнении команды, которая требует рабочую директорию, `git` ищет привязанный репозиторий в таких местах:

- переменная окружения `GIT_DIR`
- директория (или файл) `.git` вверх по дереву начиная от текущего каталога. В случае файла, там хранится путь к репозиторию.

С помощью файла или `GIT_DIR` можно сделать так, чтоб несколько рабочих директорий использовали один и тот же репозиторий.

Что касается файлов и синхронизации. Она всегда делается из объектов гита. В рабочей копии у вас хранится какая-то *одна версия* файлов, т.е. в разных версиях/ветках у вас могут быть абсолютно разные файлы. И clone/push/pull всегда использует именно репозиторий.

Comment: При этом если вам нужно только иметь несколько рабочих копий одного репозитория, то проще использовать команду git worktree